# How to pass params to method create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a method but I get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'product_params'
```

I do not understand what the problem is.

```rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: %i[show]


  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end

  private
  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
end
```

My parameters are:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"eupRBo6LO4xQbJfBSDJOC6SOesNJ0GMeBMZRHijgvXvx4pn6Lw2jeIVCQ+XjqaDl8g6Dck1WsOYMiSMa8s4UMQ==", "product"=>{"title"=>"test_title", "description"=>"test_description"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: There's no reason for this not to work, are you sure you saved your file?

Comment: of course i'm sure :)

Comment: What's full backtrace?

Comment: What do you see in params? And also paste your complete controller code

Comment: Instead of using `product_params`, use the params and see if you can create a `product`? What I mean is `@product = Product.new(title: params[:product][:title])` && `@product.save`

Comment: Another question: Are you sure you closed `created` method with `end` properly?

Comment: @Kedarnag also fails: ```↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:19:in `block in create'
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/products_controller.rb:19:in `block in create'
```

Comment: My money is on there being a missing `end` statement, after the `if` condition. I don't think the code in your StackOverflow post is the same as the code on your machine. I think you've edited it. Besides, it's not even valid -- there's an *extra* `end` statement on the last line.

Comment: If you **indent your code properly**, then issues like this become far more apparent.

Comment: When you update your question please do _not_ use "edited" or "updated" tags to mark the changes. Instead, simply incorporate the new information into the question as if it'd been there all along. We can tell when and where the question changed because SO tracks all that.

Comment: Learn to use your editor's ability to (re)indent code, and to bounce from the start and end of blocks. Knowing those things make it easy to debug this sort of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have the end for the `respond_to` block indented to look like the end of your `create` function, when in reality all of your private functions are within your create function.  Change your code to look like this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: %i[show]

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```